# DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for example-domain - check that a DNS record exists for this domain

Tags: linux, certbot

I use AWS Linux.
I want to use `certbot` to make my website from http to https.

when I run：`sudo certbot certonly --webroot -w ./ -d example——domain`

error shows：

```
Requested name http://example——domain appears to be a URL, not a FQDN. Try again without the leading "http://".
 sudo certbot certonly --webroot -w ./ -d example——domain
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
Requesting a certificate for example——domain
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for example——domain
Using the webroot path /home/ec2-user/william for all unmatched domains.
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain example——domain
http-01 challenge for example——domain
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: example
   Type:   dns
   Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for
   example——domain - check that a DNS record exists
   for this domain
```

Nginx config:

```
 server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
        # disable checking file size for upload
        client_max_body_size 0;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
                proxy_set_header HOST \$host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto \$scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP \$remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }


    location /flower/ {
            # rewrite ^/flower/(.*)$ /\$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5555/;
            proxy_set_header HOST \$host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto \$scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP \$remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

Comment: Please would you update your question with real data. This looks like a configuration issue somewhere that can only be identified by seeing what you actually have rather than an obfuscated version of it

Comment: updated , thanks @roaima

Comment: try sudo certbot certonly --nginx(optional) --webroot -w ./ -d domain without `http://`

Comment: just tried, the same error, do you have any other method? thanks

Comment: So did you actually check whether the A records exist and is accessible from public DNS servers?

Comment: It's our intranet website so of course could not be  accessible from public DNS servers

Comment: if its not accessible from public, how you expect name resolution to work from a public server?